# How to use object '_' in underscore.js

Tags: node.js, underscore.js, npm

I'm new to nodejs, the only way that I can come up with is :

```
var a = require ('./undercore-min')
```

and make use of underscore object

```
a([1,2,3]).each(function(a){console.log a})
```

but I'd love to use the elegant '_' syntax,

```
_([1,2,3]).each()
```

how to do that, and how to make underscore globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assign it.

```
var _ = require ('./undercore-min')
```